# How applying logical AND (&&) in firestore query

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to merge these queries with AND logical operator, so I just get the data that fulfilled these 2 conditions

```
.where("sportType", "in", sportFilter)
.where("floorType", "array-contains-any", floorFilter)
```

I was trying using nested `where` like this

```
                ref
                .where("sportType", "in", sportFilter)
                .where("floorType", "array-contains-any", floorFilter)
                .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        items.push(doc.data())
                    })
                    setLoading(false)
                })
```

but it comes to an error like:

```
FirebaseError: Invalid query. You cannot use 'array-contains-any' filters with 'in' filters.
```

**EDIT**

this is my collection structure, I want to get a document that has sportType Futsal and floorType Grass

```
[
{
    name: "Golden Goal",
    sportType: "Futsal",
    floorType: "Grass"
},
{
    name: "Goalie",
    sportType: "Football",
    floorType: "Grass"
},
{
    name: "Gold",
    sportType: "Futsal",
    floorType: "Vinyl"
},
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations_2): *You can use at most one `in`, `not-in`, or `array-contains-any` clause per query. You can't combine these operators in the same query.*

---

> I want to get a document that has sportType Futsal and floorType Grass.

This would be the correct query:

```js
ref.where('sportType', '==', 'Futsal')
   .where('floorType', '==', 'Grass');
```